# How to deploy angular-seed project on Heroku

Tags: heroku, angular-seed

I have tried following steps suggested in the blog below:
https://medium.com/@matheusrma/deploying-angular-seed-to-heroku-12a5bb907467

But still I get this application error: http://cryptic-depths-3702.herokuapp.com/index.html

heroko logs shows Permission denied error:

2014-10-09T18:30:46.723952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `s
cripts/web-server.js`
2014-10-09T18:30:47.606840+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: scripts/web-server.js: Permission denied

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things you need to do.

**First:** Change your Procfile to:

```
web: npm start
```

**Second:** Change your package.json to have this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/web-server.js"
}
```

**Third:** Remove the first line in web-server.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

**Finally:** You may have to scale your web dynos with:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Answer (score 2):

The `angular-seed` app has been updated since the post was written on March 10. The [old repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/tree/39004438686ddbfff1d005fdaf88ba0d57aee25e) has a directory called `scripts` that contains the web server script, but that does not exist in [the most recent version](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

It looks like the current version doesn't have anything to run on a webserver anymore, so you'll need to add something that runs content (through Grunt, Express, Gulp).

*Update*

You can use something like [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) to generate an [Angular app that comes with a working Gruntfile to serve your content](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). You can copy or move the contents from the angular-seed `app` directory and use them to replace the generated `app` directory in the project repo generated by Yeoman.